Applying to OR PhD Programs Without Real Analysis?
I’m an undergrad majoring in Mechanical Engineering with a minor in Mathematics, and I’m planning to apply to PhD programs in Applied Math or Operations Research. My research interests are in stochastic optimization, particularly applied to engineering problems. Unfortunately, my university has recently rearranged the schedule for one of my required MechE courses, which now conflicts with Real Analysis 1. This has left me in a tough spot because I know Real Analysis is often considered a critical course for math-heavy PhD programs. I’m trying to figure out the best way to move forward while keeping my application strong. Here’s some context: I’ve taken (or plan to take) these courses (excluding Real Analysis 1-2):
Calculus 1–3, Linear Algebra 1-2, Intro to Computational Math, Vector Calculus, Stochastic Models for CS, Dynamic Systems, Numerical Methods, Complex Analysis, Applied Stats 1-2, Game Theory and Applications, Programming in MATLAB 1-2, Programming in C++ 1-2, Intro to Programming in Python, Probability and Statistics for Engineering, Intro to Data Science, Differential Equations I, and Discrete Math.
Here are the options I’m considering:
Take Modern Analysis as a substitute for Real Analysis (The course description for Modern Analysis: Basic properties of real numbers. Functions. Limits and properties of continuous functions. Differential calculus). While it isn't exactly Real Analysis, I’m hoping it would demonstrate enough foundational knowledge for PhD admissions.
Delay my graduation by a year to fit Real Analysis into my schedule. This would allow me to take additional advanced math courses and maybe do a study abroad as well. However, the thought of postponing graduation isn’t great.
Apply to masters programs instead of PhD programs. I though masters programs might give me more flexibility regarding prerequisites like Real Analysis, and I could use it to strengthen my academic profile before applying to PhDs. Although from what I've heard masters are expensive.
Keep in mind most of my costs are covered by scholarships, so I am graduating debt free and if I were to take any additional semester, I wouldn't have to pay. Any advice on which path to take or how to strengthen my application would be hugely appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I would most definitely go for a masters in the area before diving into a PhD. Yes, it will give you better chances and fundamentals, but perhaps more importantly, you will get a taste of what doing research is before diving into the deep end. (This might change depending on the country, though)

I never had Real Analysis as part of my PhD study in optimization, and I regretted that. Take it your first year in the program.
